# null values in some of dataframe columns, while reading it from hbase

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am reading data from hbase using spark sql. one column has xml data. when xml size is small , I am able to read correct data. but as soon as size increases too much, some of the columns in dataframe becomes null. xml is still coming correctly.

while reading data from sql to hbase I have used this constraint:
hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize=0 in my sqoop.

Comment: when data type mismatch, HBase gives null value. I faced this issue in my code.

Comment: hi Kishore, thanks for replying. but I have not faced this null issue for other rows when xml size is small. I am facing null issue while reading hbase data as dataframe in spark.

Comment: any other information required please let me know.